# Changing Materialize CSS navbar active color

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm creating a navbar using MaterializeCSS and I added some code to change the color of the items when hover. But, when I add a class "active" to the li I don't know how to change the background color and the text color of the navbar item.

```
 <nav class="navbar-fixed">
     <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="lobby.php" class="brand-logo center">
            <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png"/>
        </a>
        <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <ul class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
 </nav>
```

My CSS:

```
nav.navbar-fixed {
  background: white;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  height: 70px;
}
.navbar-fixed .nav-wrapper {
  background: white;
  margin: 20px;
}
.navbar-fixed .nav-wrapper > ul > li > a {
  color: #faa61a;
}
.navbar-fixed .nav-wrapper > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: white;
}
.navbar-fixed .nav-wrapper > ul > li:hover {
  background-color: #faa61a;
}
.navbar-fixed .nav-wrapper .brand-logo img {
  height: 45px;
}
.navbar-fixed .nav-wrapper .button-collapse i {
  color: black;
}
```

When I hover it, it's working OK, but when I set an item as active, it's using its default background-color and color.

Comment: Can't you use whatever styles are working for `:hover` and apply them to `.active`?

Answer (score 1):

Active is a class defined in materialise css.

`nav ul li.active {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}`

You can change the color or specify any other rule by overriding this class. If this doesn't help, Can you please put the code on fiddle and share the link?